# Does it make sense to use const in an interface or not?

Tags: c++, interface, constants

I have a module that performs some calculations and during the calculations, communicates with other modules.  Since the calculation module does not want to rely on the other modules, it exposes an interface like this (this is a very simplified version of course):

```
class ICalculationManager
   {
   public:
      double getValue (size_t index) = 0;
      void setValue (size_t index, double value) = 0;
      void notify (const char *message) = 0;
   };
```

Applications that want to use the calculation module need to write their own implementation of the interface, and feed it to the calculation tool, like this:

```
MyCalculationManager calcMgr;
CalculationTool calcTool (calcMgr);
calcTool.calculate();
```

I am wondering now whether it makes sense to add "const" to the methods of the ICalculationManager interface.

It would seem logical that the getValue method only gets something and doesn't change anything, so I could make this const.  And setValue probably changes data so that won't be const.
But for a more general method like notify I can't be sure.

In fact, for none of the methods I can now for sure that the method is really implemented as a const method, and if I would make the interface methods const, I am forcing all implementations to be const as well, which is possibly not wanted.

It seems to me that const methods only make sense if you know beforehand what your implementation will be and whether it will be const or not.  Is this true?

Doesn't it make sense to make methods of this kind of interface const?  And if it makes sense, what are good rules to determine whether the method should be const or not, even if I don't know what the implementation will be?

**EDIT:** changed the parameter from notify from "char *" to "const char *" since this lead to irrelevant answers.

Comment: +1 for causing lots of discussion :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You make a function `const` when you are advertising to clients that calling the function will never change the externally visible state of the object.  Your object only has one piece of state that can be retrieved, getValue.

So, if getValue can cause the next getValue to return a different value then sure, leave it non-const.  If you want to tell clients that calling getValue() will never change the value returned by the next getValue() then make it const.

Same for notify:

```
double d1 = mgr->getValue(i);
mgr->notify("SNTH");  // I'm cheating.
double d2 = mgr->getValue(i);
assert(d1==d2);
```

If that should hold true for all cases and all i's then notify() should be const.  Otherwise it should not be.

Comment: You are assuming that the writer of the interface is also the writer of the implementation.  In this case, it is the caller of the interface that defines the interface (or contract), and since it can't know how it will be implemented, it can't know whether it should be const or not.

Comment: No. I'm not.  But I give up.  Accept the top voted answer for all the good it'll give you. -> " In this case, it is the caller of the interface that defines the interface (or contract),..." <- very much should not be!!!  You need to rethink your design methodology.

Comment: @Patrick: I think Noah's comment has nothing to do with the particular implementor -- it has to do with what the **caller** of the interface expects. (Particularly the second paragraph of the answer) The behavior/interaction of these methods in the interface **is part of the interface** -- an interface is not just what makes code syntactically valid -- it has a lot to do with what makes code semantically valid as well. If you can't think of exactly what an interface implementor should be doing i.e. how one method affects another in the interface, then the interface is wrong. @Noah: +1.

Comment: the interface conceptually not only decides the technicalities (arguments / return value), but the *meaning* of the methods. An interface can say "calling getTime() must return UTC time". If an implementation returns local time, it's implementing it wrong. Likewise, if the interface says "getValue() cannot change the externally visible state of the object", then make it const. If the interface says "the implementation can change it", then make it non-const. In short: the interface decides, the implementation must follow it. And the interface should be explicit about it.

Comment: Note that nothing mentioned in @tenfour's comment exists in code ;) -- it's the semantic meaning of the interface, not the syntactic one.

Comment: @Patrick How can you define an interface (which is a contract) and then wonder whether or not the implementer will respect that contract. It's either a contract or it isn't. What you have described is not a contract.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. One should use `const` whenever and wherever it is sensible to do so. It doesn't make sense that the method for performing a calculation (which is what your interface suggests) should change it's observable behavior because it had "notify" called on it. (And for that matter, how is notification related to calculation at all?)

My making one of the interface members `const`, you don't force clients to be `const` -- you merely allow them use of a `const ICalculationManager`.

I would probably make `Notify` `const`. If clients need to do something `non-const` as a result of a notification, then `Notify` is not a good method name -- that name suggest non-state-modifying transformations such as logging, not modification.

For instance, most of the time you pass your interface around, you're going to want to use pass-by-reference-to-const to pass the interface implementor, but if the methods aren't `const`, you cannot do that.

Comment: This answer is all messed up.  Making a function 'const' has nothing to do with anything that clients need to do.  If a client needs to do something non-const then it can; has nothing to do with if notify() is const or not.  Your last bit is a half-truth; you *might* pass a reference to base around by const-reference around 1/2 the time.  No, don't make members const whenever they can be; make them const when they *should* be.

Comment: If the implementation decides to buffer all messages given to it via notify, then it will change its internal buffers in every call to notify.  Therefore it can't be const.  Still, notify seems a good name for me.

Comment: @Patrick: Then the interface could call on some other non-const class in order to do that. My issue with the name "Notify" is that it tells you absolutely nothing about what the method is supposed to do. Is it a general log? Is it called to let the interface implementor know a calculation is about to occur? Is it even related to the function of performing the calculation at all? I wouldn't even put such a method in the same interface as the calculation because calculation and logging aren't related to each other in any way...

Comment: @Noah: Modified slightly in response to your comment, but I still think the last part of my answer is correct. Having to modify the parameters of a method indicates that the method should be refactored to be an object (i.e. "Extract Method Object") rather than returning data out via parameters.

Comment: @Billy - well over half the time you use an abstract interface it's never even passed around at all once it's been created and put where it belongs.

Comment: the interface determines the OBSERVABLE behavior, so constness should be used as Billy ONeal says - sensibly, just like in any other class. If internal stuff needs to change, use `mutable`. The observable behavior defined by the interface should not be broken by the implementation.

Comment: I only use const references. If I need to modify something, I use a pointer.

Comment: @Tom: My point is that you should never modify something passed as a parameter at all. If you need to modify a parameter, then it should be a method object, not a method, and the modified item should be a property of the method object.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Not sure I follow you. Do you mean that instead of `ModifyFoo(Foo& foo)`, you would call `foo.modify()`? I don't think this is really always practical. My only point is that if I did need to modify foo in a method, I only use pointers. Basically I *only use const references*. e.g. - `ModifyFoo(Foo* foo) { foo->DoStuff(); }`.

Comment: I basically follow the Google C++ Style Guide found here: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Reference_Arguments

Comment: @Billy: this is wrong. Use of const to qualify the value type of a function prototype parameter has no impact on the signature and is worthless confusion and so it is evil :) If the definition is also given then const can be used to prevent the implementation modifying the parameter, but this has no impact on the interface since the value is copied.

Comment: @Tom: The Google guide is fine for C++ existing in a large existing codebase of C code. For new code I'd not recommend it simply because most of the things it tells you to do (i.e. no C++ exceptions) are the result of needing to integrate with the existing C codebase at google, not necessarily as a general guide for everyone. @Yttrill: If you're passing by value okay, but generally speaking you shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: The reasons given for not using exceptions don't say anything about working with an existing C codebase. Take a look here: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Exceptions

Comment: @Tom: Err.. did you read the page? First entry you linked to, for exceptions: "However, for existing code, the introduction of exceptions has implications on all dependent code. If exceptions can be propagated beyond a new project, it also becomes problematic to integrate the new project into existing exception-free code. **Because most existing C++ code at Google is not prepared to deal with exceptions, it is comparatively difficult to adopt new code that generates exceptions**." They are talking about Google's codebase. What's right for their code might not be (probably isn't) for yours.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I'm embarrassed. To answer your question -- clearly the answer is no. When I saw what you wrote back to me I "read" the section on exceptions. That means I read the pros/cons but totally (by accident) neglected to read the "decision" section. :-o. Well, needless to say I feel pretty dumb.

Comment: @Tom: Lol -- we're all human. Just trying to prevent the FUD that is "Well Google does it, so therefore it must be good" attitude that often follows that style guide around. :)

Comment: @Tom - that section on references has to be one of the silliest things I've ever seen.  They put pros/cons in as if they're trying to be objective but then just arbitrarily state, "Don't use references for return," and never, ever give any reasoning as to why; they never WEIGH the pros/cons.  I've always sensed that the google style guide was a bunch superfluously verbose bunk; this is one more example as to why.

Answer (score 2):

The interface should be guiding the implementation, not the other way around. If you haven't decided if a method or parameter can be const or not, you're not done designing.

Using const is a way of making assertions about what the code is or is not allowed to do. This is extremely valuable in reasoning about a piece of code. If your parameter to `notify` isn't const for example, what changes would it make to the message? How would it make the message larger if it needed to?

**Edit:** You appear to know the value of declaring a const parameter, so lets build on that. Suppose you want a function to record the value of a calculation:

```
void RecordCalculation(const ICalculationManager *calculation);
```

The only methods you'll be able to call on that pointer are the const methods. You can be sure that after the function returns, the object will be unchanged. This is what I meant by reasoning about the code - you can be absolutely certain the object won't be changed, because the compiler will generate an error if you try.

**Edit 2:** If your object contains some internal state that will be modified in response to operations that are logically const, such as a cache or buffer, go ahead and use the `mutable` keyword on those members. That's what it was invented for.

Comment: Indeed the parameter of notify should be const, I agree with that.  But that doesn't answer the question relating to the methods being const or not.  My CalculationTool cannot know what the implementation of ICalculationManager is going to do in the notify.  The implementation could just send the message to std::cout (than it can be const), or it could buffer it (then it can't be const).  If I don't know what the implementation will do, how can I know whether the method should be const or not?

Comment: @Patrick - No, the clients of the interface can't, and shouldn't know what the implementation behind that interface is doing.  But see my answer.  A client can, and MUST, be able to depend on the implementation being obeyed and acting a certain way.  Your use of 'const' tells those clients what they can and can't be certain of.

Answer (score 0):

For me it only depends on the contract of your interface.

For a getter method I do not see why it should change any data and if this happens, maybe mutable is an option.

For the setter method I agree, not const there because this will certainly change data somehow.

For the notify is hard to say without knowing what it means for your system. Also, do you expect the message parameter to be modified by the implementation? If now, it should be const too.

Answer (score 0):

Without reading your entire post: Yes of course, it makes sense if you want to use an object (which inherits ICalculationManager) in a const context. Generally, you should always use const qualifier if you don't manipulate private data.

EDIT:
Like Mark Ransom said: You need to know exactly how your interface functions should behave, otherwise your not finished designing.

Comment: I don't agree.  The interface only defines the contract; not how it should be implemented.  Since I don't know how the implementation of the interface will implement the notify method (sending it to std::cout, or buffering it in a list), I can't know whether the method should be const or not.  If I DO make it const, then I might end up requiring all implementations using mutable data members, or lots of const_casts, which defeats exactly the purpose of the const keyword.

Comment: @Patrick - you are partially there.  Again, see my answer.  Mutable data members do NOT defeat the purpose of const when used correctly.

Comment: modifying private data should not be a deciding factor when using `const`.

Comment: @tenfour - Speaking from "private" data I mean every class-containing-data. So, it is a deciding factor when using const.

Comment: only externally visible state should be considered. private data is implementation-specific and is not relevant to the design of the interface. If, in an implementation, private data must change in a const method, use `mutable` to accommodate.

Answer (score -3):

I know I'm going to get a lot of downvotes for this, but in my opinion the usefulness of const-correctness in C++ is vastly exaggerated. The const idea is primitive (it only captures one bit of concept... change/don't change) and comes with an high cost that even includes necessity of code duplication. Also it doesn't scale well (consider const_iterators).

What's more important I cannot remember even a single case (not even ONE) in which the const-correctness machinery helped me by spotting a true logical error, that is I was trying to do something that I shouldn't do. Instead every single time the compiler stopped me there was a problem in the const declaration part (i.e. what I was trying to do was logically legit, but a method or a parameter had a problem in the declaration about const-ness).
In all cases I can remember where I got a compiler error related to const-correctness the fix was just adding some missing const keywords or removing some that were in excess... without using the const-correctness idea those errors wouldn't have been there at all.

I like C++, but of course I don't love to death every bit of it (digression: when I interview someone a question I often ask is "what is the part you don't like about <language> ?" ... if the answer is "none" then simply means that who I'm talking to is still in the fanboy stage and clearly doesn't have a big real experience).

There are many parts of C++ that are very good, parts that are IMO horrible (stream formatting, for example) and parts that are not horrible but neither logically beautiful nor practically useful. Const-correctness idea is IMO in this gray area (and this is not a newbie impression... I came to this conclusion after many many lines and years of coding in C++).
May be it's me, but apparently const correctness solves a problem that my brain doesn't have ... I've many others problems, but not the one of confusing when I should change an instance state and when I shouldn't.

Unfortunately (differently from stream formatting) you cannot just ignore the const-correctness machinery in C++ because it's part of the core language, so even if I don't like it I'm forced to comply with it anyway.

You may now say... ok, but what's the answer to the question ? It's simply that I wouldn't get too crazy about that part of the semantic description... it's just a single bit and comes with an high price; if you're unsure and you can get away without declaring constness then don't do it. Constness of references or methods is never an help for the compiler (remember that it can be legally casted away) and it has been added to C++ just as an help for programmers. My experience tells me however that (given the high cost and the low return) it's not a real help at all.

Comment: -1 for FUD, as well as not answering the question the OP asked.

Comment: "..I cannot remember even a single case (not even ONE) in which the const-correctness machinery helped me by spotting a true logical error, that is I was trying to do that I shouldn't do..."  

There was a memory leak in our system, the cause was that someone wrote the code to call "release()" instead of "get()" on a std::auto_ptr variable (on several places). This happened because the developer did not honored the coding guideline that we should make auto_ptr const whenever possible. If it was declared const we would have got a compilation error.

Comment: when the compiler gives you a tool that can enforce a concept at compile-time instead of run-time, use it.

Comment: So much religious fervour! I agree with the poster. Const correctness is overrated and should not have been added to the language. Many languages don't have it. Ocaml for example has "mutable" instead which is quite different. My language Felix, which models C++, doesn't provide any support for const.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: I've written quite a bit of C++ code and only came at this heretic position about const-correctness after a long time. Const correctness is something meant to help the programmer, yet in retrospect I found it didn't help much despite its quite high cost. I like C++ but this doesn't mean I must like all of it... there are parts that are simply ugly (e.g. output formatting) and parts that just don't shine neither as beautiful nor useful (some usage of const)... describing in detail why I think so would take too much for this place, my suggestion is just don't get crazy about it.

Comment: "I cannot remember even a single case (not even ONE) in which the const-correctness machinery helped me by spotting a true logical error, that is I was trying to do that I shouldn't do." <- maybe the reason you haven't done such an error in the first place is *because* of const-correctness checking? You say the compiler stopped you several times because you made errors in declaring stuff const/non-const. What if it wouldn't have stopped you...

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: compiler stopped me many times because there was an error in the declarations related to const-correctness. It's not that it wasn't ok for me for example to call a certain method, but that who wrote the class forgot to declare such a method const and being me handed a const reference I wasn't allowed to call it. The error the compiler spotted was itself in the const-correctness declaration part, not in my algorithm... so the net gain in those cases is zero, because it was solving a problem that without enforcing const correctness wouldn't even exist.

Comment: @billy oneal: I hope now I made my points clearer and I think that this text cannot be considered FUD. I also added a clear explanation of what is my suggestion (use const-correctness when you MUST, not when you CAN).

Comment: @6502: Const correctness is not a hard concept. It stops a large class of errors (accidentiallying modifying the contents of `std::basic_string::c_str()` anyone?), and is easy as hell to add to your program. You provide no data or justification for your hatred other than "well it doesn't seem to be useful for me" -- sorry, but that kind of anecdotal justification is the definition of FUD.

Comment: While we're on FUD, here, I'll spew some of my own. With the exception of my first serious C++ program (when I didn't know about `const`), it's never given me headaches or caused problems, but has stopped legitimate errors (such as modification of `c_str()`'s buffer on accident). Also, pass-by-reference seems a lot less attractive when you can't tell your clients that the object in question cannot be modified, and when you can't bind an unnamed temporary to that reference. Both of those things require `const`.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I never said that const correctness is an hard concept. Actually I think it's a primitive one... so primitive that it's not worth representing especially given C++ syntax that makes it costly and that doesn't scale well. Why some use of C++ "const" sucks however is a complex faceted subject and may be one day I'll invest the time needed to explain my position in detail, but SO for sure is not the place for that. Please just consider a trivial example... I've a list of vectors: how do I pass that to a function as a modifiable list of unmodifiable vectors?